# Differentiation of absolute value

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to differentiate `D[Abs[z],z]` and instead of `Sign[z]`, I got the following:

```
Derivative[1][Abs][z]
```

Did I do something wrong or Mathematica just does not know how to differentiate?

Comment: At the very top of the Mathematica,Stackexchange.com web page there is "Search on Mathematica..." If you type `differentiate abs` or `derivative abs` into that and tap Enter and read some of the posts on this subject then that may explain some of this to  you.

Comment: If someone can suggest a better duplicate, I can add a link.

Comment: As of version 11, there's a function `RealAbs` whose domain is restricted to reals. It is therefore differentiable, unlike `Abs`.

Comment: There's also `ComplexExpand`: `Derivative[1][Abs][z] // ComplexExpand`

Comment: Now, I try FullSimplify[Sign'[x], x \[Element] Reals]. It should give DiracDelta and it doesn't. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

For `z` real

```
Abs[z] == Sqrt[z^2] // Simplify[#, Element[z, Reals]] &

(* True *)

D[Abs[z] /. Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2], z] // Simplify[#, Element[z, Reals]] &

(* z/Abs[z] *)
```

This is only equal to `Sign[z]` if `z` is real and `z != 0`

```
% == Sign[z] // Simplify[#, Element[z, Reals]] &

(* z != 0 *)

%% == Sign[z] // Simplify[#, Element[z, Reals] && z != 0] &

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** That is,

```
D[Abs[z] /. Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2], z] // 
 FullSimplify[#, Element[z, Reals] && z != 0] &

(* Sign[z] *)
```